# How to redirect all traffic apart from certain folders in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been pulling my hair on this one. I want to redirect all traffic to my new site.

The new site is mysite.org for arguments sake. However there are certain pages and rules and folders which I want to redirect onto the new site - if the user does not visit those folders or rules - it should be a generic redirect to my site?

```
redirect 301 / http://example.org
redirect 301 /index.php http://example.org
redirect 301 /index.html http://example.org
redirect 301 /contact.php http://example.org/contact-us
redirect 301 /store-locator/list.php http://example.org/store-locator
redirect 301 /store-locator/ http://example.org/store-locator
redirect 301 /about.php http://example.org/about-us
redirect 301 /customer-care.php http://example.org/contact-us
redirect 301 /hq-location.php http://example.org/store-locator
redirect 301 /privacy.php http://example.org/privacy
redirect 301 /terms.php http://example.org/terms
redirect 301 /policy.php http://example.org/returns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` since `RedirectMatch` uses regex and matches only matched URIs whereas `Redirect` matches any URI starting with the pattern provided hence your first rule will always execute making **all subsequent rules ineffective**.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://example.org
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.(html|php)$ http://example.org
RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact\.php$ http://example.org/contact-us
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store-locator/list\.php$ http://example.org/store-locator
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store-locator/?$ http://example.org/store-locator
RedirectMatch 301 ^/about\.php$ http://example.org/about-us
RedirectMatch 301 ^/customer-care\.php$ http://example.org/contact-us
RedirectMatch 301 ^/hq-location\.php$ http://example.org/store-locator
RedirectMatch 301 ^/privacy\.php$ http://example.org/privacy
RedirectMatch 301 ^/terms\.php$ http://example.org/terms
RedirectMatch 301 ^/policy\.php$ http://example.org/returns
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. /store-locator/ will not redirect but /store-locator will - trailing slash?

Comment: You should test in Chrome dev too with cache disabled.